# Angular: How to debounce a function call with Observable.timer() and switchMap?

Tags: angular, observable

This is my method:

```
  filter(value) {    
    this.backendCall(value)    
  }
```

I would like to put a **delay between backend calls** so that my method does not get called on every keystroke with Observable.timer() and switchMap.

**As an example** I have this code from an async validator that **does precisely what I want**:

```
export function createAsyncValidator(checkFn: (value: string) => Observable<Boolean>, errorMessage: string) {
    return (control: AbstractControl): Observable<ValidationErrors> => {
        return Observable.timer(500).switchMap(() => {
            return checkFn(control.value)
                .map(result => (result ? null : { [errorMessage]: true }));
        });
    }
}
```

... but I am **struggling to apply it to my method**. This is what I have tried:

```
  filter(value) {
    Observable.timer(500).switchMap(() => {
      return Observable.of(value);
    }).subscribe(() => {
      console.log('filter', value);
      // this.backendCall(value)
    });
  }
```

**The delay is indeed applied, but all values are logged**. I was expecting the swithMap to unsubsribe those observables that arrive during the delay. **What am I missing here ?**

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use the `debounceTime` before subscribing to an observable.

In your filter function emit an event with the value and react in the subscription with added debounceTime.

```
filter(value: ValueType) {
    this.filterSubject.next(value);
}
```

**Outdated:**

```
ngOnInit() {
    this.filterSubject = new Subject<ValueType>();
    this.filterSubject.debounceTime(500).subscribe((value: ValueType) => {
        this.backendCall(value);
    });
}
```

**Newer Angular versions:**

In newer Angular (or RxJS to be precise) versions, you need to pipe operators the following way:

```
ngOnInit() {
    this.filterSubject = new Subject<ValueType>();
    this.filterSubject.pipe(debounceTime(500)).subscribe((value: ValueType) => {
        this.backendCall(value);
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First I think you just miss the return statement there :

```
filter(value) {
    -->return<-- Observable.timer(500).switchMap(() => {
      return Observable.of(value);
    }).subscribe(() => {
      console.log('filter', value);
      // this.backendCall(value)
    });
  }
```

But i dont really understand the logic you are trying to put here.

EDIT after this comment :

> I would like the backend call to happen only when I am done typing
>   (with a delay of a second for example). Throttle would send my first
>   keystroke to the backend right away

You could simply use the debounceTime operator to implements such behavior.

[doc here](https://github.com/Reactive-Extensions/RxJS/blob/master/doc/api/core/operators/throttle.md)

So if you source is an input you could use it that way :

```
<myFormControl>.valueChanges.debounceTime(500).flatMap(value => {
    return this.backendCall(value);
}).subscribe();
```

This way, the backendCall will be called 500ms after you stop typing.

Comment: I would like the backend call to happen only when I am done typing (with a delay of a second for example). Throttle would send my first keystroke to the backend right away.

Comment: Adding the return statement does not change much, all keystrokes are sent with a delay.

Comment: I think your first logic is crooked with the delay operator usage. It cants achieve what you want. It will only delay the call to backendCall and its whats delay operator is meant for.

Comment: My first logic was crooked indeed. Inside the filter method it was already to late to throttle anything. It needed to be restricted from outside. Now that I think about it, I feel silly :) Thanks anyway